# Correctly decoding hex escaped unicode strings in python

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup, robobrowser, mojibake

I am using RoboBrowser (which uses BeautifulSoup) to extract links from a website, some of these links contain unicode characters. However I am having trouble getting python to interpret it correctly.

For example, a link contains this Cyrillic character

> п

Which is URL encoded as

```
%D0%BF
```

Beautiful soup will spit out

```
u'\xd0\xbf'
```

Which looks correct to me but prints out

> Ð¿

which corresponds to the byte array

```
'c3 90 c2 bf'
```

The correct encoding appears to be

```
u'\u043f'
```

Which gives the correct byte array and also prints correctly

```
u'\u043f'.encode("utf-8").encode("hex")
'd0bf'
```

---

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong so the question is how do I get from

```
u'\xd0\xbf' to u'\u043f'
```

Comment: What code are you using to get it from the page? The URL is correctly encoded, something is decoding the URL-encoded *bytes* as Latin-1, rather than UTF-8.

Comment: You can fix this by using `.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')` but I want to see if there is anything that can be done to avoid the issue in the first place.

Comment: `u'\xd0\xbf'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')`

Comment: Awesome, perfect
@martijn-pieters
I am doing something along the lines of
`a = domObject.select('a')`    `url = urllib.unquote(a.get("href"))`
Also, I don't quite get why u'\xd0\xbf', is that not the correct byte sequence?

Comment: Hmm, looks like i've been blaming the wrong component, looks like it is a urllib bug https://bugs.python.org/issue8136 which was deemed too dangerous to fix and this is now the 'intended' behavior

Comment: In Python 3, [`urllib.parse.unquote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) defaults to UTF-8 and is configurable. The Python 2 equivalent just gives you Latin-1, unconditionally.